# Flutter - Type "Null" is not a subtype of type "Widget" error

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am getting a "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'" for this page.  Not sure what's causing the error.  I've looked at stack and can't determine the cause.  I'd love some help on this.  Thank you!

CHECKOUT PAGE Code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import '../services/payment_service.dart';
import '../utils/app_colors.dart';
import '../widgets/widgets.dart';

class CheckOutPage extends StatefulWidget {
  DocumentSnapshot? eventDoc;

  CheckOutPage(this.eventDoc);

  @override
  State<CheckOutPage> createState() => _CheckOutPageState();
}

class _CheckOutPageState extends State<CheckOutPage> {
  int? selectedRadio = 0;

  void setSelectedRadio(int val) {
    setState(() {
      selectedRadio = val;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
      firstDate: DateTime(2015),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
    );
  }

  String eventImage = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

// Get Single Event Image
    try {
      List media = widget.eventDoc!.get('media') as List;
      Map mediaItem =
          media.firstWhere((element) => element['isImage'] == true) as Map;
      eventImage = mediaItem['url'];
    } catch (e) {
      eventImage = '';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          // height: Get.height,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 27,
                      height: 27,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage('assets/circle.png'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Image.asset('assets/bi_x-lg.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Center(
                      child: myText(
                        text: 'CheckOut',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 23,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: AppColors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Text(''),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                width: Get.width,
                height: 150,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: AppColors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      blurRadius: 2,
                      spreadRadius: 1,
                      color: Color(0xff393939).withOpacity(0.15),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 150,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          image: NetworkImage(eventImage),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                // Get Event Name
                                myText(
                                  text: widget.eventDoc!.get('event_name'),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    color: AppColors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 25,
                                ),
                                myText(
                                  text: 'may 15',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    color: AppColors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: 11.67,
                                height: 15,
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  'assets/location.png',
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 5,
                              ),
                              myText(
                                text: widget.eventDoc!.get('location'),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 7,
                          ),
                          myText(
                            text: widget.eventDoc!.get('date'),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 13,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              color: AppColors.blue,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: Get.height * 0.04,
              ),
              myText(
                text: 'Payment Method',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 16,
                        height: 12,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/Group1.png',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      myText(
                        text: 'Add Card detail',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 13,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Radio(
                    value: 0,
                    groupValue: selectedRadio,
                    onChanged: (int? val) {
                      setSelectedRadio(val!);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              textField(text: 'Card Number'),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 48,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: Get.height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        onTap: () {
                          _selectDate(context);
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Expiration date',
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: Get.width * 0.04,
                  ),
                  Expanded(child: textField(text: 'Security Code'))
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: Get.height * 0.01,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  myText(
                    text: 'Other option',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 13,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Radio(
                    value: 1,
                    groupValue: selectedRadio,
                    onChanged: (int? value) {
                      setState(() {
                        setSelectedRadio(value!);
                      });
                    },
                    activeColor: AppColors.blue,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                    width: 48,
                    height: 34,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/paypal.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  myText(
                    text: 'Paypal',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Radio(
                    value: 2,
                    groupValue: selectedRadio,
                    onChanged: (int? value) {
                      setState(() {
                        setSelectedRadio(value!);
                      });
                    },
                    activeColor: AppColors.blue,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                    width: 48,
                    height: 34,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/strip.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  myText(
                    text: 'Stripe',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Radio(
                    value: 3,
                    groupValue: selectedRadio,
                    onChanged: (int? value) {
                      setState(() {
                        setSelectedRadio(value!);
                      });
                    },
                    activeColor: AppColors.blue,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Divider(),
              Row(
                children: [
                  // Event Fee
                  myText(
                    text: 'Event Fee',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  // Get Event Price
                  myText(
                    text: '\$${widget.eventDoc!.get('price')}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Divider(),
              Row(
                children: [
                  // Total Events
                  myText(
                    text: 'Total Events',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  // Total Price
                  myText(
                    text: '\$${int.parse(widget.eventDoc!.get('price')) + 2}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: AppColors.blue,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                height: 50,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: elevatedButton(
                  onpress: () {
                    // if (selectedRadio == 3) {
                    //   makePayment(context,
                    //       amount:
                    //           '${int.parse(widget.eventDoc!.get('price')) + 2}',
                    //       eventId: widget.eventDoc!.id);
                    // }
                  },
                  text: 'Book Now',
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  textField({required String text}) {}
}
```

Here is the stack:

```
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  CheckOutPage
  CheckOutPage:file:///Users/jeffbarra/FlutterDev/Projects/gathr_app/lib/pages/event_page_view.dart:395:39

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _CheckOutPageState.build (package:gathr_app/pages/check_out_page.dart:253:15)
#1      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5198:27)
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5086:15)
#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#5      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5068:5)
#6      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5242:11)
#7      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5062:5)
...     Normal element mounting (24 frames)
#31     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3971:16)
#32     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6570:36)
#33     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6582:32)
...     Normal element mounting (9 frames)
#42     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3971:16)
#43     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6570:36)
#44     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6582:32)
...     Normal element mounting (178 frames)
#222    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3971:16)
#223    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6570:36)
#224    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3708:18)
#225    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6153:32)
#226    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6595:17)
#227    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#228    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#229    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#230    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#231    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#232    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#233    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#234    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#235    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#236    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#237    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#238    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#239    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#240    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:107:11)
#241    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#242    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#243    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#244    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#245    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#246    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#247    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#248    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#249    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#250    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:107:11)
#251    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#252    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#253    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#254    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#255    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#256    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#257    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#258    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#259    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#260    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#261    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#262    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6442:14)
#263    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#264    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6442:14)
#265    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#266    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#267    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#268    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#269    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#270    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#271    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#272    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#273    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2780:19)
#274    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:903:21)
#275    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:358:5)
#276    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1284:15)
#277    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1214:9)
#278    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1072:5)
#279    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:142:13)
#280    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:359:5)
#281    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:112:31)
```

Here is the code line from the page where the "relevant error-causing widget" is:

```
Get.off(() => CheckOutPage(widget.eventData));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's at the very end of that file.  You have a function named textField() that is used in places that implies it will be returning a Widget but it is returning Null.  Try changing it to:

```
  Widget textField({required String text}) {
    return Text(text);
  }
```